# Css positioning and photo resizing

Tags: html, css

I am in trouble with positioning and photo resizing. Here is the picture:

[image]

1 block - it's a photo and should be always visible all (without scrollbar!), and the 2 and 3 block size depends on window size. How should i do that?

Comment: try table with 3 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a play.

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $photoheight = $('.photo').css('width');
     $('.photo').css('height', $photoheight);
     $(window).resize(function(){
       $photoheight = $('.photo').css('width');
       $('.photo').css('height', $photoheight);

       });
     });
</script>
<style>
.photo {
        min-width:200px;
        width:25%; 
        max-width:400px;
        background-image:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KWHpPk4f-kM/TdZY_dxWMRI/AAAAAAAAADc/6FHVzBLY-4o/s1600/flower-1.jpg');
        background-position:center center;}
</style>


<body>
<div class="photo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use min-width and max-width if you place and centre the image with CSS but I don't know how you could do it vertically.

Possibly JavaScript/jQuery script.